# MATLAB - Error bars separation distance and height

Tags: matlab, errorbar

I have data arrays w and x; I want to plot error bars y distance apart and z distance above and below the points. Is there a way to do this? I've tried manipulating the errorbar function but can't figure it out.

w [1
3
5
8
9
15
17
34
67
79
90
123
63
23
2
]
 x[1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15]

plot(x,w)hold on;
errorbar(x,w....not sure what to put after);

I'm trying to plot error bars every 3rd point and with a height of +-5

Comment: Yes there is. Show your code with sample data that we can use. thanks

Comment: so did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply draw the error bars yourself

```
for idx = 1:3:length(w)
    plot([x(idx) x(idx)],[w(idx)+5 w(idx)-5]);
end
```

Alternatively you could give a handle to the errorbar function, but I'm not sure if it allows you to modify this stuff.

Comment: Is there a way to plot horizontal bars this way as well?

Comment: Yes, you could move the +5 and -5 to the x-coordinates instead of the y coordinates. It's logical if you understand the plot command; something like this: plot([a b],[c d]) will plot a line from (a,c) to (b,d). However, you should also be able to manipulate this directly from the errorbar function (see @Benoit_11)

Answer (score 0):

By setting the right `Properties` of the `errorbar`object you can get what you need.

Note the `LData` and `UData` properties, which are used to specify the height below and above the bars as well as the `XData` and `YData`.

```
clear
clc
close all

 w = [1 3 5 8 9 15 17 34 67 79 90 123 63 23 2 ]; 
 x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15];

 %// Set location on x axis
 loc = 1:3:numel(w);

 plot(x,w)
 hold on; 

 hErr = errorbar(loc,w(loc),'rx','LData',5,'UData',5,'XData',loc,'YData',w(loc));
```

Output:

[image]